# What is the name of the standard error stream (Apache+php)

Tags: php, stream, stderr

I want to put some text into the Apache error log (listens on the stderror error stream) from PHP using file_put_contents.
I am missing the name of this stream, and whether I have to put :// or something similar before it.

Thanks

Comment: Writing an entire file to a log seems like an **extremely** bad idea to me.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - not sure what you mean, but file_put_contents is an easy way to add stuff into files/streams. I am using it in development, this is not production code.

Answer (score 2):

See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

```
$log = fopen("php://stderr", "a"); 
fwrite($log, "test message"); 
fclose($log);
```

But you might want to use the [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function instead.

Answer (score 2):

From http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

`php://stdin`, `php://stdout` and `php://stderr` allow direct access to the corresponding input or output stream of the PHP process. It is recommended that you simply use the constants `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers.